# Ipod application compatibility

Tags: iphone

Is any iphone application can run into ipod with proper screen resolution?

I am little bit confuse among designing that if i make an application for iPhone and iPod so should i need to design different screen for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPod and iPhone currently have the same size screen.  As other commenters noted, there are differing models between retina and non-retina which have different resolution, so you will have provide @2x and normal size graphics for them.

However, the iPad has vastly different screen size and resolution.  If you only write for the iPhone/iPod, you can run on the iPad too but it will only use a small portion of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is basically the same. However, you need to take care of the device capabilities, e.g. the iPod has no phone functionality (if you intend to make use of it).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the iPod touch and the iPhone have the same screen size. They may have different resolutions, but the screen size is the same and apart from providing image assets at different sizes there should be no issues.

Comment: thanks friends for your suggetion . As you said if both screen has same size then application would work properly so designing screen via code or designing screen via available tools which one is beeter approach?